# Out of process COM server in MTA issues

Tags: delphi, com, mta

We have an out-of-process server running in MTA in a standalone application with UI.

Server is initialized in following way.

Scenario 1

```
initialization  begin
  CoUninitialize;
  CoUninitialize;
  CoUninitialize; //i have to call it three times to be able to initialize the MTA
  OLECHECK(ComObj.CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED));
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, MyServer,
     Class_MyServer,ciMultiInstance, tmFree);
end;
```

I just start the app and then close without any clients attached to it.
During close following error occurs: `Runtime error 216 at 00408A2E` I'm not able to track it down it seems it is related with COM and I think that I'm doing something wrong.

The error does not occurs if I initialize the server in STA

```
initialization  begin
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, MyServer,
      Class_MyServer,ciMultiInstance, tmSingle);
end;
```

Scenario 2

I've also tried to create a thread in initialization section and create the server in `Thread.execute` and there is no error during close but clients does not discover the first instance of the server and instead activate another one.

```
procedure TDCOMThread.Execute;
var dwReturn:DWORD;
    Msg:TMsg;
    H:THandle;
begin
    OleCheck(ComObj.CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED));
    TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, MyServer,
         Class_MyServer,ciMultiInstance, tmFree);
    H:=EVentStop.Handle;
    while true do
    begin
       dwReturn:=MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1,H,false,200,QS_ALLINPUT);
       case dwReturn of
         WAIT_OBJECT_0: break;
         (WAIT_OBJECT_0+1): begin
             while PeekMessage(msg,0,0,0,PM_REMOVE) do
               Dispatch(Msg);
         end;
         WAIT_TIMEOUT:begin
                           while PeekMessage(msg,0,0,0,PM_REMOVE) do
                             Dispatch(Msg);
                        if Terminated then
                         break;
                      end;
         WAIT_FAILED:begin
              break;
         end;
         WAIT_ABANDONED:
         begin
           break;
         end;

       end;
    end;
    CoUninitialize;
end;
```

Initialization section

```
 initialization  begin
        EVentStop:=Tevent.Create(true);
        EVentStop.ResetEvent;
        DThread:=TDCOMThread.Create(true);
        DThread.Resume;
    end;
```

Could you give any advice how to  initialize Server in MTA and to bypass following issues:

1. Do not gives error during close
2. When server have been started manually clients to not launch another instance of the server application - this issues comes when i use a thread to init the server

Comment: If you `CoUninitialize` thrice, shouldn't you `Coinitialize` three times as well? Someone else did it before you and the next `CoUninitialize` is expected to just decrement and in your case if would terminate MTA completely...

Comment: Scenario 1 is so wrong it doesn't deserve further consideration. You're CoUninitializing under the feet of Delphi's COM infrastructure.

Comment: This is like blowing up 3 layers of foundation under a building in order to install a pipe.

Comment: ok i understand that it is the wrong way. But how would be correct to initialize the server in MTA. I ve tried in separate thread but then if server is started manualy client launch another instance instead to connect to started one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scenario 2 try to call RegisterClassObject from newly created factory.
In case of factory created in main thread - RegisterClassObject called automatically.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me, addressing option '2'.

Comment: I solved it months ago  using  CoRegisterClassObject and CoRevokeClassObject. Which is exactly the same so i`ll accept answer as valid.